# Really Messed Up in Github/Git. Should I rebase? Or what?

Tags: git, github, pycharm, repository

Ok so I really messed up with github. I am working on a project on Computer A. I created a github repo and then pushed all my commits to it. Then I wanted to add some changes but for some reason it wasn't working and my authors got all messed up because I didn't do it correctly. Anyway out of frustration I deleted my github repo. Now how do I repush the files into a new repo I created, instead of the old one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, delete the old GitHub remote attached to your repo (usually the remote name is called `origin`):

```
$ git remote rm *remote-name*
```

Next, add the new one:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_REPO.git
```

Finally, push all your commits to the new repo:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have local clones you can repush.
If you have done arbitrary resets, you can recover objects using reflogs